# Youtube embedded video won't start

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, uiwebview

I have a weird issue with my embedded youtube video. So I have a webview. I load the URL of the youtube video. When I run the App, everything is fine. The webview loads the video. BUT, when I click on the red play button. Nothing is played. The video won't start. Moreover, when I click on the title of the video. It takes me to the real "Youtube Player" if we can say that. And now if I hit the play button, it starts the video.

When I see tutorials on this everything seems working fine for them. Not for me... NEED HELP ! I am frustrated....

Here is the code part which is handling this :

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

func initilize()
{    
    let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q0oIoR9mLwc"
    webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(webView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(webView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)\"?&inline=\"1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)   
}
```

EDIT SOLUTION: Look like Music video from VeVo does that !! Insane !! Wonder Why ?! But as @MohanSingh said It was the URL link. He also made some modification on the inline handling of the video.

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

func initilize()
{    
    let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JMEEdFz0d7Q"
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let width  = webView.frame.width
    let height = webView.frame.height

    webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(width)\" height=\"\(height)\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)   
}
```

Regards,

Hary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this! `webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true` used to playing the video on inline.

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initilize()

}

func initilize()
{
    let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q0oIoR9mLwc"
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let width = webView.frame.width
    let height = webView.frame.height

    webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(width)\" height=\"\(height)\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am trying your code. But the issue is still there. I don't know why but the video won't start at all if I click on the red button. I have to click the title and then the play button.

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah! this can't play. I don't sure, but i sure the problem is with your youtube URL (i think family safety) . try different URL. for example `https://www.youtube.com/embed/zh4WiBMyJ2Q` . after the clicking red button then the black button appeared. but no needs to click. it would playing in short time depends on your network speed.

Comment: Nice !! I think  "Vevo" music video are the problem ! Wow thank you sir !!